# What order do the events from the "Inuyasha" series (movies included) occur in the timeline?

Tags: inuyasha

I'm wondering what order I should watch everything from the "Inuyasha" series in? I know there's the main series ("Inuyasha") to watch, but I don't know what point in the timeline the movies are supposed to take place. I also don't know if there's another series that continues on from the main series (kinda like how "Naruto Shippuden" continues on from the events in "Naruto"). Also, if there are any OVA episodes or specials in the series, could you please include them in the timeline as well?

Answer (score 2):

All movies can be seen after they meet Sango.  There is no chronological order to see the movies except you see them as how they got released. 
You can watch the movies with out any problem in the Inuyasha chronological order.  I guess after they meet Sango and she becomes another member of their gang,  and before the Inuyasha final season since some characters die in the last season and few of those do comeout in the movies, all 4 movies can be seen between those episodes. They are not canon so they do not affect the Inuyasha main story or are even mentioned in the series.